# How to find the mean of a Pandas DataFrame exactly a year from the starting date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to find the yearly means of a data set based on the first datetime index. 
Assume the following DataFrame:

```
    Date/Time                 speed       
2015-03-21 14:00:00           11.256
2015-03-21 14:10:00           13.789
2015-03-21 14:20:00           16.297
2015-03-21 14:30:00           11.259
...                              ...
2018-03-21 14:00:00            8.211
2018-03-21 14:10:00            5.324
2018-03-21 14:20:00            5.316
2018-03-21 14:30:00            2.982
```

What i am trying to achieve is to find the **mean** of the data between:

- **2015-03-21 14:00:00** and **2016-03-21 13:50:00**
- **2016-03-21 14:00:00** and **2017-03-21 13:50:00**
- **2017-03-21 14:00:00** and **2018-03-21 13:50:00**

I am familiar with grouping by year using Pandas but it does not give me the results I want. Another solution is to manually slice the dataframe, but that will be very time consuming if the dataframe contains 10s of years of data.

Is there a built in method in Pandas (or maybe any other library) to do this?

Comment: Did you try offsetting the resample to match your time period? There is a `loffset` parameter that you can use.

Comment: @NeillHerbst May you help me out with the `loffset` parameter. I went through the documentation and ended up writing this `means = df.resample('1Y', loffset=datetime.timedelta(days=-21, weeks=-12, hours=-14)).mean()`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I added an answer. It should work but you will see that it does not account for leap years. It is probably the only major drawback of this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with leap years, so resample or `Timedelta` is not possible use, simpliest is loop with range by minimum and maximum years and seelcting with f-strings:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

rng = pd.date_range('2015-03-21 14:00:00', '2018-03-21 14:30:00', freq='10T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed':np.random.randint(1000, size=len(rng))}, index=rng)
#print (df)


out = pd.Series({x: df.loc[f'{x}-03-21 14:00:00':f'{x+1}-03-21 13:50:00', 'speed'].mean()
                   for x in range(df.index.year.min(), df.index.year.max()+1)})
print (out)
2015    501.062879
2016    498.546385
2017    498.490963
2018    580.250000
dtype: float64
```

Another solution is more complicated, but also working nice with leap years - idea is split each year to 2 parts - before thresh datetime and after and then sum together.

```
#datetime for thresh - always need leeap year like 2000
date = pd.Timestamp('2000-03-21 14:00:00')
#replace all years to 2000 and test data fr matched conditions
mask = pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime('2000-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) < date
arr = np.where(mask, 'matched','nonmatched')

#sum of means have no sense, so need working mean = sum/count
df1 = df.groupby([arr, df.index.year])['speed'].agg(['sum','size'])
print (df1)
                      sum   size
matched    2016   5811589  11604
           2017   5725034  11460
           2018   5702078  11460
nonmatched 2015  20596429  41100
           2016  20478564  41100
           2017  20498607  41100
           2018      2321      4
```

---

```
#data before thresh datetime
matched = df1.loc['matched']
matched.index -= 1
print (matched)
          sum   size
2015  5811589  11604
2016  5725034  11460
2017  5702078  11460

#data after thresh
nonmatched = df1.loc['nonmatched']
print (nonmatched)
           sum   size
2015  20596429  41100
2016  20478564  41100
2017  20498607  41100
2018      2321      4

#sum both DataFrames and divide sum by counts for mean
df2 = matched.add(nonmatched, fill_value=0)
out = df2['sum'].div(df2['size'])
print (out)
2015    501.062879
2016    498.546385
2017    498.490963
2018    580.250000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I wanted to check if there was any library that had this already built in, I guess I will just write a more general function based on your answer.

Comment: @Tabbakhh - added another solution working also with leap years, please check edited answer.

Comment: I tested your code on another dataset and it got really close to the correct answer! The results from your code are the following `2015 : 8.177520
2016: 8.756599` while the correct results (computed manually) are as follows: `2015: 8.232503 , 2016: 8.756599`. I am currently working on finding out why the first year's mean is not correct (unlike the second year)

Comment: @Tabbakhh How do you count it manually? Do you cout with leap years?

Comment: Sorry I should of been more clear about how I got the 'correct' results. I just manually sliced my data frame for every year and found the mean. If I use the example I placed in the question, The first year will be from **2015-03-21 14:00:00**  until **2016-03-21 13:50:00`**

Comment: @Tabbakhh - Yes, I think manually count is by `out = pd.Series({x: df.loc[f'{x}-03-21 14:00:00':f'{x+1}-03-21 13:50:00', 'speed'].mean()
                   for x in range(df.index.year.min(), df.index.year.max()+1)})`. Do you get different outputs? Because in my answer are 2 different solutions and get same outputs, so I think it is correct.

Comment: @jazrael I have your first solution, the one you just suggested, already coded and it gives me the exact same answer as me manually slicing the data frame and finding the mean.

Comment: @Tabbakhh - And for second solution you get different output?

Comment: The first solution works perfectly, but the second does not for the first year only. I will accept the first solution as it works but I am not sure about the second. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

To select timestamps of a DataFrame `df` with a datetimeindex, use `df.loc`:

```
start = df.index[0]
dt = pd.Timedelta(1, unit="Y")
first_year_mean = df.loc[start:start+dt].mean()
```

Comment: What is not working? Does it throw an error (if so, please report it here), or doesn't it deliver the desired result?

Comment: It does not deliver what desired. If my df starts from **2015-03-21 14:00:00**, your code takes the mean between **2015-03-21 14:00:00** and **2016-03-20 19:49:12** (what I got from running your code) when the desired results are the means between **2015-03-21 14:00:00** and **2016-03-21 13:50:00**

Comment: Not what I expected, but `pd.Timedelta(1, "Y")` yields `Timedelta('365 days 05:49:12')`... you could use `pd.Timedelta(365, "d")` or `pd.Timedelta(366, "d")` depending on the year :)

Comment: `pd.Timedelta(1, "Y")` does yeild to `Timedelta('365 days 05:49:12')`, add that to the start date and you get **2016-03-20 19:49:12 **. I wanted a library that will automatically take care of the days per year rather than manually changing the code

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use the `loffset` parameter of `pandas.DataFrame.resample`.

```
deltaTime = datetime.datetime(2015,3,21,14) - datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)
resampled_df = df.resample('Y', loffset=deltaTime).mean()
```

The only downfall of this method is that it does not adjust the timedelta for leap years. If this is not that important to you, then this is probably a good method to follow.

Comment: Tested but did not produce the correct results. I got the same results as running `resampled_df = df.resample('Y').mean()` without `loffset`.